# Custom Extension not loading .phtml template

Tags: module, blocks, theme

I've created an extension which seems to be partially working but not executing any of the code in the template file.

With the code in `indexAction()` just echoing, the content is output as one might expect, however with;

```
public function indexAction()
{
     $this->loadLayout(); 
     $this->renderLayout();
}
```

The page only returns the blank standard page template.

The frontname.xml file looks like this

```
<frontname_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
    <block type="core/text">
        <block type="frontname/frontname" name="frontname" template="frontname/frontname.phtml"/>
    </block>
    </reference>
</frontname_index_index>
```

Config.xml contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Newmodule_Frontname>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Newmodule_Frontname>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <frontname>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Newmodule_Frontname</module>
                <frontname>frontname</frontname>
            </args>
        </frontname>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <frontname>
                <file>frontname.xml</file>
            </frontname>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <frontname>
            <class>Newmodule_Frontname_Block</class>
        </frontname>
    </blocks>
</global>
</config>
```

Block/Frontname.php:

```
class NewModule_Frontname_Block_Frontname extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{
 public function myfunction(){
    return "Tesing123";
   }
 }
```

EDIT

I've found the exception trace as follows:

```
        exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Newmodule_Frontname_Block_Frontname' in /path/to/app/Mage.php:595
        Stack trace:
        #0 /path/to/includes/src/__default.php(27814): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
        #1 /path/to/includes/src/__default.php(27756): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('frontname/front...', Array)
        #2 /path/to/includes/src/__default.php(27791): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('frontname/front...', 'frontname')
        #3 /path/to/includes/src/__default.php(27558): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('frontname/front...', 'frontname')
        #4 /path/to/includes/src/__default.php(27524): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
        #5 /path/to/includes/src/__default.php(27529): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
        #6 /path/to/includes/src/__default.php(13911): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
        #7 /path/to/includes/src/__default.php(13836): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
        #8 /path/to/app/code/local/Newmodule/Frontname/controllers/IndexController.php(6): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout()
        #9 /path/to/includes/src/__default.php(13985): Newmodule_Frontname_IndexController->indexAction()
        #10 /path/to/includes/src/__default.php(18380): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
        #11 /path/to/includes/src/__default.php(17910): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
        #12 /path/to/includes/src/__default.php(20535): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
        #13 /path/to/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
        #14 /path/to/index.php(102): Mage::run('', 'store')
        #15 {main}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure following points.

1. Make sure you have `frontname` part of your custom layout update handle `frontname_index_index` is defined inside your `config.xml` file. (or show us your `config.xml` if possible)
2. Try this code first.

   ```
   <frontname_index_index>
       <reference name="content">
           <block type="core/template" name="frontname" template="frontname/frontname.phtml"/>
       </reference>
   </frontname_index_index>
   ```

   and make sure you have your template file does exist in your package/theme design directory. ie at `app\design\frontend\{package}\{theme}\template\frontname\frontname.phtml`
3. If the above step worked, then you can try this.

   ```
   <frontname_index_index>
       <reference name="content">
           <block type="frontname/frontname" name="frontname" template="frontname/frontname.phtml"/>
       </reference>
   </frontname_index_index>
   ```
4. If step 3 didn't work, then that indicates you have no such block types `frontname/frontname`. So define that then.

We can give more specific informations if you can show your `config.xml` file. Let me know your doubts. Good luck

### EDIT

You block is not working because, you have a wrong class definition. Your class name should be `NewModule_FrontName_Block_Frontname` instead of `NewModule_FrontName_Block_FrontName`. (Also make sure, block file name should be `app/code/local/NewModule/FrontName/Block/Frontname.php`)

**or**

keep your block class name as it is and update the block layout definition like this (in this case, block file name should be `app/code/local/NewModule/FrontName/Block/FrontName.php`.

```
 <block type="frontname/frontName" name="frontname" template="frontname/frontname.phtml"/>
```

Comment: @Wren Everything looks good in `config.xml` file. So try the second solution first. If that showed the content of your template file, then go for third step. let me know whether you are facing any diffculties

Comment: Thanks very much for this. So, step 2 works for me, but then changing the type back to "frontname/frontname" takes me back to where I started; I've added the NewModule/FrontName/Block/FrontName.php above

Comment: it also looks good. double check the file path. make sure `<?php` is present very above that file. and also make sure, you have used step3 in my answer. clear your cache.

Comment: `<?php` tag is present and correct, but still no joy. The path to the Block file is "app/code/local/NewModule/FrontName/Block"

But it's still not being picked up... Is the any way to trace the route from the XML to the Block definition?

I've turned the cache off completely.

Comment: Other than this.. I cant see any problem with your codes. Lastly, please check for any log errors..

Comment: Thank you very much for your help -- I'm a bit happier that I'm not going totally mad - but I'm still at a bit of a loss as to what exactly is wrong. The log files are clean but still no output.

Thanks again and best wishes.

Comment: @Wren got your issue. Your class name should be `NewModule_FrontName_Block_Frontname` instead of `NewModule_FrontName_Block_FrontName`. Way to go man

Comment: @Wren please see my edit

Comment: Thank Raj, I've just tried the Case changes - but no luck - I think I'd been desperately trying various combinations to see if any worked...

Comment: @RajeevKTomy I have similar issue and posted it here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83856/custom-layout-not-loading-for-custom-module can you check if possible?

Answer (score -1):

Please check the below link. This consist the same thing which you wish to implement

http://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_hello_world

Comment: The link only answers are treating as bad because the answer become unuseful if the link become idle. So try to put a short view of that link with your answer if possible. Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid that this doesn't quite address my problem, I'm able to echo from the IndexController without any issue - the problem is specifically loading the phtml via the Block definition.

Thank you.