# Custom layout not loading for custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, module, render

I have created a custom module.

Below is my app/etc/modules/Php_CardReload.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Php_CardReload>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Php_CardReload>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Below is my app/code/local/Php/CardReload/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Php_CardReload>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Php_CardReload>
    </modules>
    <global>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <reload>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Php_CardReload</module>
                    <frontName>reload</frontName>
                </args>
            </reload>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <cardreload>
                <file>php_cardreload.xml</file>
            </cardreload>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</config>
```

Below is my controller

```
<?php
    class Php_CardReload_MtoMController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
        function reloadCardAction(){
        $this->loadLayout();
            $this->renderLayout();

        }
    }
?>
```

Below is my php_cardreload.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.0.1">
<default>    
        <reference name="top.links">
            <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
                <action method="addCartLink"></action>
                <action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="right">
            .
            .
            .
        </reference>
    </default>
    <cardreload_mtom_reloadcard>
        <reference name="content">
            <!--<block type="cardreload/cardreload" name="cardreload" template="cardreload/cardreload.phtml" />-->
            <block type="core/template" name="cardreload" as="reload" template="page/card-summary.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </cardreload_mtom_reloadcard>
</layout>
```

But the page.card-summary.phtml is not rendering. 
Also no log captured on system.log.

Comment: Please add this `print_r($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());` to your controller after `$this->loadLayout();` so you can see what are the actual handles. Most probably in your **php_cardreload.xml** you have to change `<cardreload_mtom_reloadcard>` to `<reload_mtom_reloadcard>`.

Comment: @michael I printed as you said and the output is `Array ( [0] => default [1] => STORE_default [2] => THEME_frontend_default_my_store [3] => reload_mtom_reloadcard [4] => customer_logged_out ) ` so I changed `<cardreload_mtom_reloadcard>` handle into `<reload_mtom_reloadcard>` now only the header and footer is loading not the main content.

Comment: check complier is enable or not?

Comment: @AmitBera I enabled the compiler but still only the header and footer is loading.

Comment: I noted one interesting behavior. I delete all the php_cardreload.xml content and kept it empty still the header and footer is loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some mistakes which I can see in your files;

**1. layout file declaration is placed in wrong place**

Layout definition should be inside `frontend` node. ie code should look like

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <cardreload>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Php_CardReload</module>
                <frontName>reload</frontName>
            </args>
        </cardreload>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <cardreload>
                <file>php_cardreload.xml</file>
            </cardreload>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

**2. Router configuration i**s wrong

your router unique identifier should be `cardreload` instead of `reload`. See above for the change.

**3. controller class is wrong**

Your controller class should be `Php_CardReload_MtomController` instead of `Php_CardReload_MtoMController`. Make sure path to your controller is `app\code\local\Php\CardReload\controllers\MtomController.php` instead of `app\code\local\Php\CardReload\controllers\MtoMController.php`

**3. Controller action method is wrong.**

It should be `reloadcardAction` instead of `reloadCardAction`.

After all changes made, please do clear your cache. Let me know whether it works or not

Comment: Awesome.. Thank you so much.. You saved one whole day :-) When I read your other post I thought you would solve this

Comment: @version.beta glad to help you out

Answer (score 1):

```
Replace your code with this:   
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Php_Cardreload>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
            </Php_Cardreload>
        </modules>
    </config>
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Php_Cardreload>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
            </Php_Cardreload>
        </modules>
        <global>
        </global>
        <frontend>
            <routers>
                <cardreload>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>Php_Cardreload</module>
                        <frontName>reload</frontName>
                    </args>
                </cardreload>
            </routers>
        </frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <cardreload>
                    <file>php_cardreload.xml</file>
                </cardreload>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </config>
 -------------------------------------   
    <?php
        class Php_Cardreload_MtomController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action 
        {
            function reloadcardAction(){
                $this->loadLayout();
                $this->renderLayout();

            }
        }
    ?>


   ------------------------------- 
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout version="0.0.1">
    <default>

            <reference name="top.links">
                <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
                    <action method="addCartLink"></action>
                    <action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>
                </block>
            </reference>
            <reference name="right">

            </reference>
        </default>
        <cardreload_mtom_reloadcard>
            <reference name="content">
                <!--<block type="cardreload/cardreload" name="cardreload" template="cardreload/cardreload.phtml" />-->
                <block type="core/template" name="cardreload" as="reload" template="page/card-summary.phtml"/>
            </reference>
        </cardreload_mtom_reloadcard>
    </layout>
```

Comment: What have you changed on the above? Can you add some comments